# sql select statement giving more rows then records in tables

Tags: sql, mysql, oracle

The error is very simple.

There are 3 Tables,

Lets name them A, B, C - All of them have 7 rows.

A has the following data

1
2
3
4
5
6
7

with Id = 1

B has the following data

8
9
10
11
12
13
14

with Id = 1

C has the following data

15
16
17
18
19
20
21

with Id = 1

Now i am selecting them as : select A.col1,B.col1,C.col1 from A,B,C where A.ID= B.ID and C.ID= A.ID and B.ID= C.ID.

So the output thats coming is 343.

now what i want the output to be is simply number from 1 to 21 like :

1
2
3
4
5
6
7
8
9
10
11
12
13
14
15
16
17
18
19
20
21

Please help me get out of this trouble and suggest me a fine tune query.

Comment: Rather than obfuscating your example, it would be easier to debug more "real world" examples.  As it stands I'm left confused.

Comment: because you are using this construct in your FROM clause:  "from A,B,C" you are going to get 7x7x7 rows (343) in your result because that construct creates a cartesian join. Use an INNER JOIN instead (see http://www.devshed.com/c/a/MySQL/Understanding-SQL-Joins/ for more details.

Comment: Your query is producing a cross product because the join clause is ambiguous.  For every row in A, there are 7 matching rows in B and for every row in B there are 7 matching rows in C.  As noted by Leslie, 7x7x7 is 343 which is the correct number of rows for the query as written.

Answer (score 3):

Try:

```
select col1 from a
union
select col1 from b
union
select col1 from c
```

Answer (score 2):

You could maybe use UNIONs? e.g. if it's ID 5 you want to pull stuff back with:

```
SELECT col1
FROM A
WHERE ID = 5
UNION
SELECT col1
FROM B
WHERE ID = 5
UNION
SELECT col1
FROM C
WHERE ID = 5;
```

This will put them all in a single column, rather than giving you a 7 x 7 x7 combination

Answer (score 0):

You can use a subquery like this to reduce the number of places you have to state col1 = X to one.

```
SELECT col1 FROM 
(
  (SELECT id, col1 FROM A)
  UNION ALL
  (SELECT id, col1 FROM B)
  UNION ALL
  (SELECT id, col1 FROM C)
) AS ABC 
WHERE id = 5;
```

The query optimizer should be able to apply the filter appropriately on each table before the UNION ALL is performed.

EDIT: Fixed to constrain by id as hilighted by @jeffrey-kemp)

Comment: this will result in just one row: `5`. perhaps you meant to query on ID?

Comment: Thank you Jeffrey, my SQL is rusty.

Answer (score 0):

Given your query that's exactly what you should get - 343 rows ( = 7 * 7 * 7).  Because all the rows in each table have the same ID (1) the query in your question is equivalent to doing a Cartesian join of the tables, i.e. a query with no WHERE clause where all the rows in each table are each joined to all the rows of the other tables - something like

```
SELECT A.COL1, B.COL1, C.COL1
  FROM A, B, C;
```

As others have suggested, a UNION is a good way to get what you want as it seems you're not really trying to join information from the rows together:

```
SELECT COL1 FROM A
UNION ALL
SELECT COL1 FROM B
UNION ALL
SELECT COL1 FROM C;
```

Share and enjoy.

Comment: Drat - didn't see @Leslie's comment on the original post.  Well, perhaps this adds enough value to avoid downvotes.